# Find the area of shaded region

Tags: geometry, area

In the figure given below, $\Delta \ ABC$ is right $\Delta $, $\angle B  =  90 ^{\circ}$, $AB = 28 \ cm$ and $BC = 21 \ cm$. With $AC$ as diameter, a semicircle(though it may seem like one but it is) is drawn and with $BC$ as radius, a quarter circle is drawn. Find the area of shaded region(in red colour).
[image]

I named different parts of the figure as I, II, III and IV for the sake of convenience. such as in the following figure:
[image]

So now I did the following

> ar(semicircle) = II + III,  ar(triangle) = I + IV,  ar(quadrant) = I + II
>
> We need to find the area of III + IV
>
> III + IV = (II + III) + (I + IV) - (I + II)
>
> Thus ar(shaded region) = ar(semicircle) + ar(traingle) - ar(quadrant), which in my case turns out to be $428.75 cm^2$ while the answer to the question given in the book is $688.625 cm^2$.

Is my approach to the question wrong or is the answer given in the book wrong?

Comment: Could you find an equation for the circle with radius AB and with radius BC? In that case, integrate the former and subtract the integral of the latter.

Comment: radius AB or AC?

Comment: Sorry, diameter AC.

Comment: i did area of semicircle with radius AC is $1/2 * \pi * 35^2$ and area of quarter with BC as radius is $1/4 * \pi * 21^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\text{red area} &= \text{area of }\Delta ABC + \text{area of semi-circle} - \text{area of quadrant} \\
&= \tfrac12 \times 21 \times 28 + \tfrac12 \pi \left(\tfrac{35}{2}\right)^2 - \tfrac14 \pi (21)^2 \\
&= 294 + 481.0563 - 346.3606 \\
&= 428.6957
\end{align}
$$
So it looks like you are right and your book is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

$S=S_{ABC}+S_{semicircle}-S_{quatercircle}=28.21/2+(7\sqrt{7})^2\pi/2-21^2\pi/4=6.49+\frac{7}{2}\pi.49-49\pi$

[image]

Comment: I did it can you please verify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The semi-circle with $AC$ has area$= \frac{\pi}{8} AC^2 = \frac{\pi(28^2+21^2)}{8}=\frac{1225\pi}{8}$

Area of $\triangle ABC =\frac{1}{2}AB\times BC= 294$

Area of Quadrant$= \frac{\pi}{4} BC^2=\frac{441\pi}{4}$

Required area$= \frac{1225\pi}{8}+294- \frac{441\pi}{4}=294-\frac{784\pi}{8}$ sq. unit.

Comment: Your semi-circle area is wrong, I think.